# How should I use each_with_object on Hashes?

Tags: ruby

I would like to use `each_with_object` on a hash but can't figure out how I should use it. Here is what I have:

```
hash = {key1: :value1, key2: :value2}
hash.each_with_object([]) { |k, v, array| array << k }

NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass
```

Is it possible to use `each_with_object` on hashes? If yes, what is the syntax?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Use `()`:

```
hash.each_with_object([]) { |(k, v), array| array << k }
```

Comment: WHere i can find informatin about the `()` in blocks arguments?

Comment: @andfb18 see [Enumerator description](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html#method-i-each_with_object). Blocks and arguments could be puzzling sometimes. I could recommend the most excellent blocks introduction in Chapter 5 of [Head First Ruby](http://headfirstruby.com).

Comment: @andfb18 It's called "Array Decomposition" and you can learn about it [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.3/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition).

Answer (score 1):

For someone who wants to return a new hash:

```
hash = {"a": 100, "b": 200, "c": 300}

hash.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), new_hash| new_hash[k] = v if v > 100 } # => {:b=>200, :c=>300}
```

Answer (score -3):

I have idea about that. You can use

```
output =[]
Hash.each_with_index do |e, index| 
  // do something with e. E is aray. e have 2 items.
  // First item of e is key.
  // Last item of e is value.
  // index start with 0.
  // using << with output here.
end
```

Comment: Does not answer the question at all.

Comment: This right. Class of e is Array. Only using array you want to add with << .